# checking memory leakage in qt_creator

Tags: qt-creator, memory-leaks

Can somebody please explain, is it possible to check memory leakage in qt creator, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. However you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), but it might pick up any leaks in the Qt itself. Give it a go and see if it works.

Alex